# Error API 27 SDK con buildozer

Tags: python, sdk

intento generar un apk con buildozer en una máquina virtual. Me tira el siguiente error

```
build failed requested api target 27 is not available install it with the sdk android tool
```

Y se crashea en las instrucciones del buildozer.spec

```
ANDROIDAPI = '27'
ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
```

revisando mi sdk tengo la api 19. Pero al hacer los cambios en el buildozer.spec no lo reconoce.
Tengo el jdk 8.
He visto que es un error medianamente recurrente este. Pero no logro resolverlo. Ya cloné el python-for-android